# How to implement Factory Pattern for components in a React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

Im currently using React in my company for building our main Software product... The development of the app was started a year ago, and we don't expected that our app growed so much like it does. Now we are dealing with some kind of problems that could have been avoided if we had done a good architecture design from the beginning .

For summarize, one of the most central problems that we have is the code duplication... and the large amount of "import" statements with relative routes in the top of each new component that we make...

I would like to know if is recommended for solve this kind of problems use the Factory Pattern for reusing the React components and how to successfuly implement it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have any scenario for using Factory pattern IMO. The only similar is actionCreator, but that's for redux. Boil down to the resue, If you design your component correctly, you could design a navbar or foobar or etc reusable with `props` or `children`. By the way, you should show the duplication code, that make more sense to answer.

Comment: what is that `large amount of import` means in practice? 20-30 is still normal. 50-100 can indicate that you have to chunk your components to smaller ones. I suggest that keep the single responsibility of the components instead of using the factory pattern.

Comment: @gazdagergo is about 10 to 15 maximun...

Comment: It's totally ok. That is how react works, lots of small components, only responsible for some particular task and a parent use 10-15 from them. It is no issue here I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a factory pattern in this way,

```
function ReactComponentFactory(contentsJSX){
  // do factory stuff here...
  return <div>{contentsJSX}</div>
}
```

But in my opinion this makes the code harder to grok so I'd avoid using a factory for react components.

Comment: what you recommend for this?